# ERROR while running the application using hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

> org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelector.resolveDefaultableStrategy(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/concurrent/Callable;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:705)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:122)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:92)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:124)
>     at APPLICATION.ASSIGN3_2_STORE.main(ASSIGN3_2_STORE.java:31)

```
 StandardServiceRegistry ssr=new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("ASSIGN3_2.cfg.xml").build();  
        Metadata meta=new MetadataSources(ssr).getMetadataBuilder().build();  

        SessionFactory factory=meta.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();  
        Session session=factory.openSession();  
      TypedQuery query=(TypedQuery) session.createQuery("from ASSIGN3_2");
```

Comment: NoSuchMethodError means that you're using jar files that are incompatible with each other.

Comment: yes it worked perfectly